# Simulating dynamic systems and postprocessing

Tags: javascript, performance, processing.js

Inspired by this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/208924/problems-implementing-lattice-boltzmann-method), I modified the script to run a simple simulation of [Taylor-Green vortex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%E2%80%93Green_vortex) using [LBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_Boltzmann_methods) and post-processes it using [P5*js](http://p5js.org/) (an official Javascript port of the [Processing](https://processing.org/) API). Unfortunately, it is not performing well, but as I am new to Javascript programming, I lack the insight to really optimize the code. Getting some advice and suggestions for improvement would be greatly appreciated.

A working codepen version can be found [here](http://codepen.io/nlooije/pen/MaoEMJ).

```
// 2D vector class
function vec2(x,y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
vec2.prototype = {
    scale: function(s){
        return new vec2(this.x*s,this.y*s);
    },
    add: function(v){
        return new vec2(this.x+v.x,this.y+v.y);
    },
    subtract: function(v){
        return new vec2(this.x-v.x,this.y-v.y);
    },
    dot: function(v){
        return this.x*v.x+this.y+v.y;
    },
    length: function(){
        return Math.sqrt(this.x*this.x+this.y*this.y);
    },
    normalise: function(){
        var l = 1/this.length();
        return new vec2(this.x*l, this.y*l);
    },
};

// domain class
function domain(nx, ny) {
    this.nx = nx; // domain width
    this.ny = ny; // domain height
    this.f = []; // distribution array
    this.ftmp = []; // temporary array
    this.dens = []; // density array
    this.vel = []; // velocity array
    this.omega = 1; // relaxation frequency
    this.e = [ // discrete velocity set
        new vec2(0,0),
        new vec2(0,1), new vec2(1,0), new vec2(0,-1), new vec2(-1,0),
        new vec2(1,1), new vec2(1,-1), new vec2(-1,-1), new vec2(-1,1)
    ];
    this.w  = [ // weights
        4/9, 
        1/9, 1/9, 1/9, 1/9, 
        1/36, 1/36, 1/36, 1/36
    ];
    // Arrays initialization
    for (var x=0; x<this.nx; x++) {
        this.f[x] = [];
        this.ftmp[x] = [];
        this.dens[x] = [];
        this.vel[x] = [];
        for (var y=0; y<this.ny; y++) {
            this.f[x][y] = [];
            this.ftmp[x][y] = [];
        }
    }
}
domain.prototype = {
    init: function(){
        // Initializes Taylor-Green vortex
        var kx = 2*Math.PI/this.nx;
        var ky = 2*Math.PI/this.ny;
        var kxkx = kx*kx;
        var kyky = ky*ky;
        var ksq = kxkx + kyky;
        var k = Math.sqrt(ksq);
        var dens0 = 1;
        this.umax = 0.1;
        var u0 = 4*this.umax;
        this.densmax = dens0 + 3*dens0*u0*u0/4; 
        for (var x=0; x<this.nx; x++){
            for (var y=0; y<this.ny; y++){
                var u = u0*ky/k*Math.cos(kx*x)*Math.sin(ky*y);
                var v = -u0*kx/k*Math.sin(kx*x)*Math.cos(ky*y);
                this.dens[x][y] = dens0 + 3*dens0*u0*u0/4*(kyky/ksq*Math.cos(2*kx*x)+kxkx/ksq*Math.sin(2*ky*y));
                this.vel[x][y] = new vec2(u,v);
                for(var i=0; i<9; i++){
                    // Initialize using equilibrium distribution
                    var uu = this.vel[x][y].x*this.vel[x][y].x + this.vel[x][y].y*this.vel[x][y].y;
                    var eu = this.e[i].x*this.vel[x][y].x + this.e[i].y*this.vel[x][y].y;
                    this.f[x][y][i] = this.w[i]*this.dens[x][y]*(1+3*eu+4.5*eu*eu-1.5*uu);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    collide: function(){
        for(var x=1; x<this.nx-1; x++){
            for(var y=1; y<this.ny-1; y++){
                // calculate density
                var rho = 0;
                for(var i=0; i<9; i++){
                    rho += this.f[x][y][i];
                }
                this.dens[x][y] = rho;

                // calculate velocity
                var u = new vec2(0,0);
                for(var i=1; i<9; i++){
                    u  = u.add( this.e[i].scale( this.f[x][y][i] ) );
                }
                u = u.scale( 1/rho );
                this.vel[x][y] = u;

                // Perform collision step and save to temp array ftmp
                var uu = u.x*u.x + u.y*u.y;
                for(var i=0; i<9; i++){
                    var eu = u.x*this.e[i].x + u.y*this.e[i].y;
                    var fiEq = this.w[i]*rho*(1+3*eu+4.5*eu*eu-1.5*uu);
                    var fiCol = -this.omega*(this.f[x][y][i]-fiEq); // bgk
                    this.ftmp[x][y][i] = this.f[x][y][i] + fiCol;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    periodic: function(){
        // Apply periodic boundary conditions on ftmp
        // x-periodic
        for(var y=1; y<this.ny-1; y++){ 
            for(var i=0; i<9; i++){
                this.ftmp[0][y][i] = this.ftmp[this.nx-2][y][i];
                this.ftmp[this.nx-1][y][i] = this.ftmp[1][y][i];
            }
        }
         // y-periodic
        for(var x=1; x<this.nx-1; x++){ 
            for(var i=0; i<9; i++){
                this.ftmp[x][0][i] = this.ftmp[x][this.ny-2][i];
                this.ftmp[x][this.ny-1][i] = this.ftmp[x][1][i];
            }                        
        }
        // corner treatment
        for(var i=0; i<9; i++){
            this.ftmp[0][0][i] = this.ftmp[this.nx-2][this.ny-2][i];
            this.ftmp[this.nx-1][this.ny-1][i] = this.ftmp[1][1][i];
            this.ftmp[this.nx-1][0][i] = this.ftmp[1][this.ny-2][i];
            this.ftmp[0][this.ny-1][i] = this.ftmp[this.nx-2][1][i];
        }
    },
    stream: function(){
        // Perform streaming step ftmp -> f
        for(var x=1; x<this.nx-1; x++){
            for(var y=1; y<this.ny-1; y++){
                for(var i=0; i<9; i++){
                    this.f[x][y][i] = this.ftmp[x-this.e[i].x][y-this.e[i].y][i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
function simulation(){
    var sim = function(p) {
        var nx = 200, ny = 200;
        var myDomain = new domain(nx, ny);
        p.setup = function() {
            p.createCanvas(nx, ny)
             .parent('sim');
            //p.frameRate(30);
            myDomain.init();
            p.noStroke();
            p.colorMode(p.RGB, 1);
        }
        p.draw = function() {
            myDomain.collide();
            myDomain.periodic();
            myDomain.stream();
            var dens = myDomain.dens;
            var vel = myDomain.vel;
            var densmax = myDomain.densmax;
            var umax = myDomain.umax;
            for (var x = 0; x < p.width; x++) {
                for (var y = 0; y < p.height; y++ ) {
                    //var v = dens[x][y]/densmax;
                    var v = vel[x][y].length()/umax;
                    p.stroke(v, 0, 1-v);
                    p.point(x, y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return new p5(sim);
}
$( document ).ready(simulation());
```

*Edit 1:*
Running the profiler in Chrome results in:

[image]

This shows that most of the CPU is being used by P5*JS rather than the code.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Code Review. We only review working code; I know your code is working, but we cannot really answer "Anyone any idea why `dot` method goes wrong?"

Answer (score 2):

I found that this specific part of the processing code was performing badly:

```
for (var x = 0; x < p.width; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < p.height; y++ ) {
    // removed irrelevant code
    p.stroke(v, 0, 1-v);
    p.point(x, y);
  }
}
```

It turns out that this write to the screen at every `point`. It is much better to buffer the writes by `set`-ting the pixels to certain color and then writing the whole buffer using `updatePixels()` like:

```
for (var x = 0; x < p.width; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < p.height; y++ ) {
    // removed irrelevant code
    p.color(v, 0, 1-v);
    p.set(x, y, c);
  }
}
p.updatePixels();
```

Now the `draw` calls take up about as much time as the `collide` calls (about 35%). I'm still looking to reduce this further.